# Remove all labels on Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm using the `Mapbox Dark v9` style and would like to remove all the labels.

I found a list of labels [here](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/mapbox/dark-v9/).

And have tried the `map.removeLayer` function to remove some of them, e.g.:

```
map.removeLayer("place_label");
```

As well as:

```
map.removeLayer("place-city-lg-n");
map.removeLayer("place-city-lg-s");
map.removeLayer("place-city-md-n");
map.removeLayer("place-city-md-s");
map.removeLayer("place-city-sm");
```

Is there a way to remove labels from a style?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're just looking for a dark basemap without labels — i.e. it's not important for you to remove them programmatically at runtime — you can create a new style in [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/) using the Dark template and use the style editor to select and delete all label layers. You can then publish the style and use its url in your app.

[image: screenshot]

If it *is* important for you to remove all label layers at runtime, you could do something like

```
map.style.stylesheet.layers.forEach(function(layer) {
    if (layer.type === 'symbol') {
        map.removeLayer(layer.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a note that that will also remove layers that are symbols, not text "labels". Checking for the presence of a `text-field` property is probably safer.

Comment: Can you say how to get this dark map without any labels in mapbox

Comment: it is not possible to delete main layers now. But we may just hide them.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for resurrecting an old question that came up when I Googled it. My goal was to be able to toggle the labels on and off at will, so I modified the above code to this:

```
let show = false; //or true, etc.                   
map.style.stylesheet.layers.forEach(function(layer) {
    if (layer.type === 'symbol') {
        map.setLayoutProperty(layer.id,"visibility", show?"visible":"none");
    }
});
```